# Как преобразовать одномерный массив в дву-мерный

Tags: java, массивы

Допустим у меня есть одномерный массив

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

и мне надо преобразовать его в двумерный массив

```
int[][] b = {{1,2,3},
             {4,5,6},
             {7,8,9}}
```

Вот для чего мне надо разбивать массив (Для уровня в игре)

[image: array level]

Я тупой помогите(

Comment: самокритичненько... а чего просто циклом не пройдете?  int [][] b = new int[3][3]; for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) b[i/3][i%3] = a[i];

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы числа были динамическими т.е x 2 - y 5 или x 13 - y 52.
Я проверил он не работает на x 2 - y 5(

Comment: @ Akram динамически - это вы имеете в виду размер массива? в вашем примере массив 3*3 вот я его для примера и взял, но цикл то к размеру не привязан

Comment: Я там написал **допустим**, чтобы вы поняли что они не статические.
Мне нужно чтобы оно работаро динамически типо x 6723 - y 2939 или x 1 - y 1

Comment: @ Akram так оно и работает динамически. создавайте целевой массив любого размера и запускайте с ним цикл

Comment: `int[][] b = new int[2][5];
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i/2][i%5] = a[i];
        }`

Не работает тут, там не обезательно чтобы было полное заполнение можно и масил на 100 и один элемент заполненый еденицей типо :
`[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]` или `[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,0,0,0]]`

Comment: @ Akram во-первых, о том, что размеры массивов не совпадают, вы ничего не написали. во-вторых, это решается проверкой на выход за пределы массива.

Comment: Я хотел сказать что мне нужно то что будет "надламавать" масив на **5** 
на пример то что он выходит под конец не важно оно становится нулем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил следующим образом.

Если поменять `lengthX` или `lengthY` то код все еще
будет работать даже если он выйдет за размер массива.

```java
int lengthX = 5;
int lengthY = 6;
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
int[][] doubleArray = new int[lengthX][lengthY];
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lengthX; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < lengthY; j++) {
        try {
            doubleArray[i][j] = array[n];
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {
            // System.out.println(aioobe);
            doubleArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
        n++;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(doubleArray));
```

Comment: А чем мой вариант не нравится? Ваш при превышении будет все последующие случаи сначала пытаться обратиться к ф-ции и только потом выполнит код в блоке catch. Лучше уж проверку n < array.length добавьте.

Comment: Я не хочу показывать код который я использую в игре, могу только сказать что ваш код не подошол, также этот я одоптировал под код в игре.

Comment: наборы входных данных совпадают, выходной - тот же. Скажите, если у меня затесалась ошибка.

Comment: Кстати, интересный факт - примитивы по дефолту имеют значение 0. Так что можете сразу из цикла выходить при выполнении условия n < array.length

Answer (score 0):

Следует помнить, что привести в такой вид массив можно только тогда, когда из корня длины исходного массива получается целое число.

```
int[] matrix = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
double lengthInReal = Math.sqrt(matrix.length);
if(lengthInReal % 1 != 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
int doubleMatrixLength = (int) lengthInReal;
int[][] doubleMatrix = new int[doubleMatrixLength][doubleMatrixLength];

for(int f = 0; f < doubleMatrixLength; f++) {
    for(int s = 0; s < doubleMatrixLength; s++) {
        doubleMatrix[f][s] = matrix[f * doubleMatrixLength + s];
        System.out.print(doubleMatrix[f][s] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод:

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6
>   7 8 9

Если имели ввиду то, что вы изначально сами должны задавать и размер ряда, и кол-во рядов, то имеет место следующее решение:

```
final int rowLength = 3;
final int collumnLength = 5;
int[] matrix = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int doubleMatrixYLength = (int) Math.ceil((double) matrix.length / rowLength);
int[][] doubleMatrix = new int[collumnLength][rowLength];
if(doubleMatrixYLength > collumnLength) {
    for(int f = 0; f < collumnLength; f++) {
        for(int s = 0; s < rowLength; s++) {
            doubleMatrix[f][s] = matrix[f * collumnLength + s];
        }
    }
} else{
    for(int f = 0; f < doubleMatrixYLength - 1; f++) {
        for(int s = 0; s < rowLength; s++) {
            doubleMatrix[f][s] = matrix[f * (doubleMatrixYLength - 1) + s];
        }
    }
    int residueCount = matrix.length % rowLength;
    for(int s = 0; s < residueCount; s++) {
        doubleMatrix[doubleMatrixYLength - 1][s] = matrix[(doubleMatrixYLength - 1) * (doubleMatrixYLength - 1) + s];
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
for(int f = 0; f < collumnLength; f++) {
    for(int s = 0; s < rowLength; s++) {
        System.out.print(doubleMatrix[f][s] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод:

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6
>   7 8 9
>   10 0 0
>   0 0 0

Comment: Мне нужно диномическое измение типо `int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`
и вывод
`1 2 3 \n
4 5 6 \n 
7 8 9 \n
10 0 0`

Я просто делаю редакто уровней для игры, но не могу получить нужный мне результат (

думал что просто задам простой вопрос и все станет нормально

Comment: @Akram добавил решение и для этого случая

Comment: Он чуть плиже но это не все он не польностю динамический, мне нужно чтобы он не только делился на 3 но и на 4, 5, 6  или больше, типо 
`[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]`
тут он делится на 5 но при этом массивов 3.

Я все еще делаю редактор уровней для игры и там много нулей не так важно!

Он может делится не только на 5 - 3, но и на 7 - 15.

`[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12,5,8], [0,8,6,5,4,3,2], ...` Размер массива 7 но массивов может быть очень много, как и размер массивов

Comment: @Akram Так предварительно указывайте эти нюансы

Comment: @Akram изменил решение

Comment: Хорошо теперь буду болиее подробно расписовать такие нюансы. (Я тут не так давно и не знаю больше подробностей)

Comment: Если поменять 3 на 4 или 2 то выдает ошибку,
мне нужно чтобы он даже при 50 на 4 работал, то что в масивах много нулей  не важно, но мне нужно создавать уровень на основе масива

Comment: Я добавил картинку где я изпользую двумерный массив для создание уровня

Comment: @Akram изменил решение